# problem in numbering table of content

Tags: preamble

i have problem in my preamble, i observed that as the page number for the "List of Tables" is taking the page number of the last page of your document  for example Tile page (i), Declaration (ii), Certification (iii), Dedication (iv),  Acknowledgements (v), List  of  Tables (xiv) instead of (vi) . what can i do

Comment: We are flattered that you think we can read minds `:-)` but, unfortunately, most of us can't and we actually need to look at some code. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.